# How can I map over an array of colors an assign them to a <p> tag based on its index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, sanity

So I'm using Sanity.io, and I'm attempting to assign a color to a

tag. There are 3 colors that I know I can put into an array. I just don't know how to iterate over those three colors and assign that color to a

tag based on its index. Basically 3 different tags, 3 different colors. This should be simple I know, but I'm having a real brain fart. Help!

SN: In Sanity, I couldn't find anything in the v3 docs that show how to create options (colorList) for the schema anymore.

This is the code before I added Sanity...

```
const ProjectCard = ({
  index,
  name,
  description,
  tags,
  image,
  source_code_link,
}) => {
  return (
    <motion.div variants={fadeIn("up", "spring", index * 0.5, 0.75)}>
      <Tilt
        options={{
          max: 45,
          scale: 1,
          speed: 450,
        }}
        className='bg-tertiary p-5 rounded-2xl sm:w-[360px] w-full'
      >
        <div className='relative w-full h-[230px]'>
          <img
            src={image}
            alt='project_image'
            className='w-full h-full object-cover rounded-2xl'
          />

          <div className='absolute inset-0 flex justify-end m-3 card-img_hover'>
            <div
              onClick={() => window.open(source_code_link, "_blank")}
              className='black-gradient w-10 h-10 rounded-full flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer'
            >
              <img
                src={github}
                alt='source code'
                className='w-1/2 h-1/2 object-contain'
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='mt-5'>
          <h3 className='text-white font-bold text-[24px]'>{name}</h3>
          <p className='mt-2 text-secondary text-[14px]'>{description}</p>
        </div>

        <div className='mt-4 flex flex-wrap gap-2'>
          {tags.map((tag) => (
            <p
              key={`${name}-${tag.name}`}
              className={`text-[14px] ${tag.color}`}
            >
              #{tag.name}
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Tilt>
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

After Sanity...

```
const Projects = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {  
    const query = '*[_type == "projects"]';
  
    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setProjects(data);
    });
  }, []);



  return (
    <>
      {projects.map((project, index) => (
        <motion.div 
          variants={fadeIn("up", "spring", index * 0.5, 0.75)}
        >
          <Tilt
            options={{ 
              max: 45,
              scale: 1,
              speed: 450
            }}
            className='bg-tertiary p-3 rounded-2xl sm:w-[360px] w-full'
          >
          
            <div className='relative w-full h-[230px]' key={index}>
              <img 
                src={urlFor(project.imgUrl)}
                alt={project.name}
                className='w-full h-full object-cover rounded-2xl'
              />

              <div className='absolute inset-0 flex justify-end m-3 card-img_hover'>
                <div 
                  onClick={() => window.open(project.codeLink, "blank")}
                  className='black-gradient w-10 h-10 rounded-full flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer'
                >
                  <img 
                    src={github} 
                    alt="github"
                    className='w-1/2 h-1/2 object-contain'
                  />
                </div>
                <div 
                  onClick={() => window.open(project.projectLink, "blank")}
                  className='black-gradient w-10 h-10 rounded-full flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer'
                >
                  <img 
                    src={projectlink} 
                    alt="projectlink"
                    className='w-1/2 h-1/2 object-contain'
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <div className='mt-5 '>
              <h3 className='text-white font-bold text-[24px]'>{project.title}</h3>
              <p className='mt-2 text-secondary text-[14px]'>{project.description}</p>
            </div>
            
          

          <div className='mt-4 flex flex-wrap gap-2'>
              <p 
                key={index} 
                className={`text-[14px] blue-text-gradient`}
              >
                {project.tags} 
              </p>
          </div>
        </Tilt>
      </motion.div>
    ))};
  </>
  )
};
```